# MySQL connection for every host

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a winforms app in vb.net that connects to a mysql database on my webserver to read and write data, this all works fine.

But i have to allow the users ip to remote connect to the database.

Is it possible to give everyone access to the database? The user account will not have all rights an the data isn't very important if it got lost.

The user account and connection details are hard coded.

I know this isnt secure but that doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's very well possible. In your mysql privileges table you'll have to grant a wildcard (`%`) host access to the user. Then in your VB.NET code simply use the address in the connectionString.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `GRANT` permissions on the database to the same user with wildcards in the host.  More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, user_name@'%.example.com' applies to user_name for any host in the example.com domain, and user_name@'192.168.1.%' applies to user_name for any host in the 192.168.1 class C subnet.
>
> The simple form user_name is a synonym for user_name@'%'.

That way every application connects to the database from random hosts and uses the same username/password in the connection string to authenticate, and MySQL will allow it because the host part of the permissions isn't explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

> But i have to allow the users ip to remote connect to the database.

Why?

Two other options:

1 - Expose the data as a web service. It's already on the web server...
2 - Build a web app instead of a desktop app.

Comment: mysql won't allow other connections than localhost, you need to manually add an ip to connect remote.

Comment: @PandaNL: I understand that. I was questioning whether you *have* to do that. I am saying I prefer options 1 and 2 above over the solution being requested.